# Is there a config file to set a custom 404 page using IIS6 and asp classic?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

I want to set a custom 404 page.  I know that I can do this through the IIS Administrative console.  However, I'd like to tweak a file instead (Like web.config for asp.net).  This way I can provide a copy of that file to upload to another server that I can not directly administer.

**I don't trust the person in the admin role to correctly set the parameters using the admin console**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no.

This data is stored in the servers MetaBase and will require an adminstrator to set.